# Unable to update my WPF chart on the go

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, charts, wpftoolkit

I am trying to keep updating my linechart according to the updated information in my application but it keeps returning the error InvalidOperationException.

The code works fine if I input static information. My codes as follows. Appreciate any help. Thanks.

CPUEvent is firing off every second. CurrentCPU is the value of the cpu every second. This information is updated every second.

```
List<KeyValuePair<double, double>> cpuList = new List<KeyValuePair<double, double>>(); 
public int counter = 0; 

public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            CPUEvent += showChart; 
        }

private void showChart(object sender, CPUEventArgs args) //////
        {
            counter += 1;
            cpuList.Add(new KeyValuePair<double, double>(counter, args.CurrentCPU)); 
            lineChart.DataContext = cpuList;  
        }
```

Comment: Use the `ObservableCollection` class and set the `DataContext` property only 1 time in the constructor. Also after replacing List by ObservableCollection, use `Dispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action)(() => cpuList.Add ... `.

Comment: ObservableCollection works perfectly. Thanks. Do you want to change your comment to an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the goal is to update UI automatically after insertions or deletions, it is recommended to use the [ObservableCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668604%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class instead of resetting the DataContext property.

The code can be rewritten so:

```
ObservableCollection<KeyValuePair<double, double>> cpuList = new ObservableCollection<KeyValuePair<double, double>>(); 
public int counter = 0; 

public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    lineChart.DataContext = cpuList; 
    CPUEvent += showChart; 
}

private void showChart(object sender, CPUEventArgs args) //////
{
    counter += 1;
    Dispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action)(() => cpuList.Add(new KeyValuePair<double, double>(counter, args.CurrentCPU)))); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If `CPUEvent` is running on different thread (non UI thread) and if the exception was something about *invalid cross thread operation exception*, try to wrap codes accessing UI controls within `Dispatcher.BeginInvoke()` to make it executed from UI thread :

```
private void showChart(object sender, CPUEventArgs args)
{
    counter += 1;
    cpuList.Add(new KeyValuePair<double, double>(counter, args.CurrentCPU)); 

    Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
    {
        lineChart.DataContext = cpuList;
    });
}
```

Comment: When I use Dispatcher.BeginInvoke it returns error saying  - Cannot convert lambda expression to type System.delegate because it is not a delegate type.

Comment: The error seems to be with the line lineChart.DataContext = cpuList; The error additional info says: "Cannot modify the logical children for this node at this time because a tree walk is in progress." Any idea what am I missing. Thanks.

Comment: Actually I haven't heard that error message before. Maybe, it get called again before prev operation finished. Try to change `BeginInvoke` with `Ìnvoke`, `Invoke` makes calling thread to wait until operation finished.